# simple perl regular expression doesn't seem to work

Tags: regex, perl

Perl newb here.  I don't understand why the code below isn't working:

```
use strict;

my $file = shift;
open(FRED,'<',$file);
while (my $line = <FRED>) {
    if ($line ~= /(fred)/i) {
    print("$line mentions fred.\n");
    }
}
```

I keep getting the following errors:

```
syntax error at ./regex2.pl line 11, near "$line ~"

syntax error at ./regex2.pl line 14, near "}"
```

Execution of ./regex.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The match operator([`=~`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators)) has the tilde on the right-hand side, not the left:

```
if ($line ~= /(fred)/i) {
```

should be:

```
if ($line =~ /(fred)/i) {
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for regex is `=~` not `~=` so try

```
if($line =~ /fred/i) {
    print "$line mentions fred.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

The operator is =~ and not ~=